# True or false? if $p$ and $q$ divide $n$, and each is greater than $n^{1/4}$, then $n/pq$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, alternative-proof

This is exercise 16 from section 2, from Elementary Number Theory by Underwood Dudley.
It states that letters $p$ and $q$ are reserved for primes.

This is my proof, I'm not sure if it's correct:

Since $p | n$ and $q | n,$ and both are primes then
$p \leq \sqrt{n}$ and $q \leq \sqrt{n}$

Multiplying both inequalities

$pq \leq n$

$1 \leq \frac{n}{pq}$

Which means that $\frac{n}{pq}$ can be $1$, thus it must be false.

Is this correct?

If it's correct, I would love to see alternative proofs.

Comment: What if $n=4pq$?

Comment: $\frac{n}{pq}$ is 4 which is not a prime number, that is a counterexample to the statement $\frac{n}{pq}$ is a prime number, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is false as stated. For a concrete example, if $n=60$, $p=3$, $q=5$, then

$$\sqrt[4]{60}\approx 2.783 < 3,\ 5,$$

but $\frac{60}{3\cdot 5}=4$ is not prime (as MJD noted, $n=6,p=2,q=3$ is also a counterexample).

In your proof, the statement $p,q\leq \sqrt{n}$ is wrong; $p$ and $q$ cannot *both* be greater than $\sqrt{n}$ (since that would mean $pq>n$), but it is not necessarily true that both are less (consider $n=12q$ and $p=3$ for some large $q$, for example).

Comment: Isn't $6$ an obvious counterexample?

Comment: @MUD Yes. $p=2$ and $q=3$ are both $>\sqrt[4]6$, but $\frac n{pq}=1$ is not prime. This *seems* to be the kind of counterexample the OP was after, but of course simply checking the case $n=6$ is the right way to do so (as opposed to juggling some inequalities to conclude $\frac n{pq}\ge 1$, which in contrast to a concrete example such as $n=6,p=2,q=3$ does *not* by itself mean that $\frac n{pq}=1$ is possible).

Comment: @MJD Yeah. I'll update the question.